# Trying to test a HttpServletResponseWrapper inside a ResponseHeaderFilter with MockHttpServletResponse

Tags: servlets, junit, servlet-filters, cobertura

I am trying to unit test the below ResponseHeaderFilter but find that this unit test fails:

```
@Test
public void testDoFilterWithOmmissableInitParameters_ETag()
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Add allowableUserAgents initParameters
    MockFilterConfig filterConfig = new MockFilterConfig();
    filterConfig.addInitParameter("allowableUserAgents", "avaya");

    // Add allowableUserAgents initParameters
    filterConfig.addInitParameter(OMIT_KEY, OMIT_VALUE);

    // Set user-agent
    request.addHeader("user-agent", "avaya");
    response.addHeader("ETag", "someEtagHash");

    filter.init(filterConfig);
    filter.doFilter(request, response, chain);

    // THIS ASSERTION FAILS:
    assertThat((String)response.getHeader("ETag"), is(nullValue()));
}
```

Specifically, the setHeader() method when I run this in debug mode is NEVER called:

```
            chain.doFilter(request,
                                new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
                                    public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
                                        //if (!(name != null && omitHeaders.contains(name.toUpperCase()))) {
                                        if (name != null && omitHeaders.contains(name)) {
                                            super.setHeader(name, value);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

The debugger gets to the line for new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) but does not actually execute the setHeader method.

here is the entire class itself:

```
public class ResponseHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseHeaderFilter.class);

    Map<String, String> additionalHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Set<String> omitHeaders = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    Set<String> allowableUserAgents = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    boolean allowFromAllUserAgents = false;

    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
                         final ServletResponse res,
                         final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String userAgent = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("user-agent");

        if (allowFromAllUserAgents
            || (userAgent != null && allowableUserAgents.contains(userAgent))
        ) {
            logger.debug("apply ResponseHeader rules for user agent [{}]", userAgent);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : additionalHeaders.entrySet()) {
                response.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

            chain.doFilter(request,
                                    new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
                                        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
                                            //if (!(name != null && omitHeaders.contains(name.toUpperCase()))) {
                                            if (name != null && omitHeaders.contains(name)) {
                                                super.setHeader(name, value);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
        } else {
            logger.debug("User agent [{}] is not an allowable agent for this filter", userAgent);
            chain.doFilter(request, res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called once during start-up
     *
     * @param filterConfig for Filter configuration
     */
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) {

        logger.info("*** ResponseHeaderFilter.init() ***");

        // set the provided HTTP response parameters
        for (Enumeration e = filterConfig.getInitParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String headerName = (String) e.nextElement();
            String headerValue = filterConfig.getInitParameter(headerName);

            // Add the list of allowable user-agents
            // cannot be null: if (headerName != null) {
                if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase("allowableUserAgents")) {
                    // omit
                    parseToUpperCaseElements(headerValue, allowableUserAgents);
                    logger.debug("allowable user-agent's {}", allowableUserAgents);
                } else if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase("allowFromAllUserAgents")) {
                    allowFromAllUserAgents = Boolean.parseBoolean(headerValue);
                    logger.debug("allowFromAllUserAgents {}", allowFromAllUserAgents);
                } else if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase("omit")) {
                    parseToUpperCaseElements(headerValue, omitHeaders);
                    logger.debug("Omit headers {}", omitHeaders);
                } else {
                    additionalHeaders.put(headerName, headerValue);
                    logger.debug("adding header [{}] with value [{}]", headerName, headerValue);
                }
            //}
        }
    }

    protected final void parseToUpperCaseElements(final String str, final Set<String> elementKeys) {
        String[] words = str.split(",");
        for (String s : words) {
            elementKeys.add(s.trim().toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        logger.debug("destroy");
    }
}
```

This filter DOES actually work when running and DOES remove the ETag header, but when I am trying to use Cobertura for code coverage, that method is not tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code you are testing `ResponseHeaderFilter` only adds or register an anonymous `HttpServletResponseWrapper` in the `FilterChain` :

```
chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
    public void setHeader(String name, String value) { ... }
});
```

And the `FilterChain` is executed by the container itself. Your test code does nothing but passing a `FilterChain` reference.

I don't know the real type of your `FilterChain` in your test, but instead of asserting that the tag got removed (`assertThat((String)response.getHeader("ETag"), is(nullValue()));`) I would split your test in two different test.

1. Replace the anonymous `HttpServletResponseWrapper` by a full type that can be called `EtagRemoverHttpServletResponseWrapper` and make a unit test that will actually assert that on `wrapper.setHeader(...)` it etag header is omitted.
2. The first on your `ResponseHeaderFilter` which will assert that the `chain` contains a reference of type `ETagRemoverHttpServletResponseWrapper`

Hope that helps.